# Reid, Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry, Problem 4.3, showing a polynomial map is an isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-geometry

> $\varphi_n \colon \mathbb{A}^1 \to \mathbb{A}^2$ is the polynomial map given by $X \mapsto (X^2,X^n)$; show that if $n$ is even, the image of $\varphi_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{A}^1$, and $\varphi_n$ is 2-to-1 outside 0.

Miles Reid, *Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry*, Problem 4.3. (first part)

Showing $\varphi_n$ is 2-to-1 is simple. Clearly $\pm \alpha$ both map to the same element, and these are the only two.
If it is 2-to-1, how can it be an isomorphism ? How can there be an inverse (polynomial) map, to $\varphi_n$, when it's not injective?

Comment: The image is isomorphic ... No one's saying $\varphi_n$ gives the isomorphism. Is this all over an algebraically  closed field?

Comment: P.S. Nice name :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) It is false that if $n$ is even the map $\phi_n$ is 2-to-1 outside zero:
That map is *injective*  if the base field $k$ has characteristic $2$  .

2) It is false even in characteristic $\neq 2$ that if $n$ is even the image of $\phi_n$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1(k)$:
For example, if $k=\mathbb F_3$ then  $\mathbb A^1(k)$ has three elements whereas the image of $\phi_n$ has only 2 .

3) If $k$ is algebraically closed of characteristic $\neq 2$, the result is indeed true:
The image of $\phi _n$ is the curve $Y=X^{\frac n2}$, which is isomorphic to $\mathbb A^1(k)$ like all graphs of regular functions $\mathbb A^1(k)\to\mathbb A^1(k)$ .

Comment: Georges: I believe (but don't have the book here at home to check) that Reid has everything over $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Dear @Ted,  it is a bit ambiguous: at the beginning of the paragraph  Reid writes: "The reader who assumes throughout that $k=\mathbb C$ will not lose much, and may gain a psychological crutch."  But to tell the truth it doesn't really matter: if I answer a question I don't forbid myself to make remarks that go beyond   what was  actually asked if I think they might have some interest, maybe to other users than the OP.

Comment: Sure, understood :) Interesting, though, that his exercise is false without the assumption. :P I expected that char 2 would definitely cause a problem.